# How to add .bash_profile in Windows to run Matlab-based IPython notebooks

Tags: bash, matlab, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm looking at this tutorial to run matlab code in IPython notebook:
http://anneurai.net/2015/11/12/matlab-based-ipython-notebooks/.

but I am stuck at step3:
I edited the .bash_profile file located at "C:\Users\myUserName.bash_profile" by
adding the following line

```
export MATLAB_EXECUTABLE="/c/Program\ Files/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/matlab.exe"
```

How can I check if the line I added is correct?
Now I do not know how to proceed:which is the terminal? 
Can I start jupyter directly via the icon?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is not possible to use Matlab kernel in IPython notebook in Windows. See this post:
https://github.com/arokem/python-matlab-bridge/issues/226

You need to first make sure that pymatbridge works fine but as it mentioned in the above link, it is different from one computer to the other.

Answer (score 1):

I went to Start > Control Panel > and typed "Environment" in the search bar. Then I clicked "Edit environment variables for your account". I clicked "New..." and added a variable named `MATLAB_EXECUTABLE` with the value `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\matlab.exe` (replace this with the path to your matlab.exe).

Now I can select Matlab from the available kernels (after restart with `jupyter notebook`).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using a Windows environment, which doesn't have an equivalent to the Terminal built-in. If you successfully installed Anaconda, however, you should be able to open the ipython notebook from there.